# Can't receive all contents of mail

Tags: email

[image: screenshot of mail i received](This are just some of my code for the HTML to cut it short), i don't get it why i can't get the value inputted by the user for the email while i can get values of others like NAME, PHONE, COMPANY etc. can you help me what's wrong? i'm a beginner so please try to be nice. THANK YOU

```
   HTML:
        <form action="contact_sendmail.php" method="post">
        <label for="first name"> First Name *</label><br>
        <input class="textbox" type=text autofocus id="Fname" name="Fname"   maxlength="50"size="30" value=""  required>        
        <br>
        <label for="last name"> Last Name *</label><br>
        <input class="textbox" type=text  id="Lname" name="Lname"   maxlength="50"size="30" value=""  required>         
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email * </label> <br>
        <input class="textbox" type="text"  id="email"    maxlength="50"size="30" value=""   required>      
        <input  class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">



    MAIL FUNCTION:

     <?php
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $msg = 'Name: '.$_POST['Lname']  .$_POST['Fname'] ." \n"
      .'Email: '.$_POST['email'] ."\n"
      .'Phone Number: '.$_POST['phone'] ."\n"
      .'Company: '.$_POST['company'] ."\n"
      .'Number of Employees: '.$_POST['employee_num'] ."\n"
      .'Comment: '.$_POST['comment']  ;



      mail('example@gmail.com', 'sample contact us Form', $msg);

     ?>
     "<script>" alert('successfully sent'); "</script>" 
     <?php
      }else {
       header('location:contact.php');
       exit(0);}

       ?>
```

Comment: You forgot the name for the email field. You specified just the id for the input field, not the name. You should add `name="email"` in your HTML.

Comment: ok, I'll try it first :)